# Issue when unsubscribing from onSnapshot listener?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following custom react hook ,

```js
// React
import { useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
// Firebase
import { db } from '../../../firebase/firebase';
import { Timestamp, doc, onSnapshot, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
// Redux
import { useAppSelector } from '../../../redux-store/hooks';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
// Contenxt
import { authContext } from '../../../context/auth/AuthState';
// Utilities
import { errorHandling } from '../../../utilities/errorHandling';
import { generateId } from '../../../utilities/generalHelperFunctions';
import { getDeviceTypeOS } from '../../../utilities/userAgentHelperFunctions';

type UnsubscribeFunction = () => void;
let unsubscribe: null | UnsubscribeFunction = null; // Store the unsubscribe function

const useSessionHandler = () => {
  // Context
  const { SignOut } = useContext(authContext);
  // Redux
  const currentUser = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.currentUser);
  // Dispatch
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // Local state
  const [isSessionValid, setIsSessionValid] = useState<boolean>(false);

  // Initiate the session
  const useMemoizedSession = useMemo(() => {
    return { loginId: generateId(), deviceType: getDeviceTypeOS(), online: true, timeStamp: Timestamp.now().toDate().toString() };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser && currentUser.authenticated && currentUser?.uid) {
      const setAppSession = async () => {
        try {
          // A. Create New (at first time) || Overwrite the currnet session in the database
          await setDoc(doc(db, 'data-users-sessions', currentUser.uid), {
            ...useMemoizedSession,
          });

          // B. Now Listen to the session changes in the database
          const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
            doc(db, 'data-users-sessions', currentUser?.uid),
            (docSnapshot) => {
              const fireBaseSession = docSnapshot.data();
              if (fireBaseSession) {
                console.log('fireBaseSessionId', fireBaseSession?.loginId);
                console.log('SessionId', useMemoizedSession.loginId);
                if (useMemoizedSession.loginId !== fireBaseSession?.loginId) {
                  unsubscribe();
                  SignOut('forceSignOut');
                } else {
                  setIsSessionValid(true);
                }
              }
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log('error', error, 'useSessionHandler onSnapshot');
              errorHandling(error, 'An error has happened', 'useSessionHandler onSnapshot', dispatch);
            }
          );
        } catch (error) {
          errorHandling(error, null, 'useSessionHandler setAppSession', dispatch);
        }
      };
      setAppSession();
    }

    return () => {
      // Note: this will unsubscribe from the onSnapshot listener when unmounting thr main component, that is technically renders when we enter /app
      // Note: and after a forceSignOut is being triggered this will unmount since we are redirecting to '/' home.
      if (unsubscribe) {
        unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  }, [currentUser]);
  return [isSessionValid];
};

export default useSessionHandler;
```

an I am getting

> Error FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

after sining out from the app for some reason my unsubscire logic is not working the hook is called in one place here

```js
const AppPrivateRoute: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  // Redux
  const currentUser = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.currentUser);
  const authenticating = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.authenticating);
  const isSessionValid = useSessionHandler();

  return authenticating ? <LoadingComponent action={'Authenticating'} /> : currentUser?.authenticated && isSessionValid ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/' />;
};

export default AppPrivateRoute;
```

and if I console.log the unsubscribe it shows null yet the error still showing for more info,
the inner sign-out works fine if is called from with in but if I sign-out directly from auth then the error happen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it intentional that you are declaring a new unsubscribe function inside the effect? if yes then there's a mistake on your function because you are trying to call the function itself rather than the function outside the hooks. But if not then I suggest reassigning the value instead of creating a new function by removing the word const

Comment: Your answer is partially right , my big mistake was I was not reassigning the variable but rather declaring it again … thus preventing the unsubscribe from happening.

Comment: Please refactor you answer , so it could apply the new concept , if someone later do the same mistake that I did….

Comment: Yes this confused me I was finding the purpose of the function outside the hooks